# Lock button in Powerpoint Custom Ribbon

Tags: xml, vba, powerpoint, ribbonx

Problem:
I have a lock button (toggle button) on my custom ribbon. Basically that "lock and unlock" the "Aspect ratio" of the text box. 
Also i wanted few points to cover while preparing it - 
 - And I wanted to run the event, whenever I select the text boxes/shape/image, if its aspect ratio is already locked then my "Lock" button need to highlight in the ribbon. vice versa
 - If I select multiple text boxes/shape/images with few are lock and few are unlock, then it must unhighlight the "lock" button in the ribbon.
- I am just unclear what to write in the event. pls help

Module Code:

```
Sub Lock_and_Unlock(control As IRibbonControl, pressed As Boolean)
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTriStateToggle
End Sub
```

Class Module (event):

```
Private Sub App_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)

If Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange = ppSelectionShapes Then
If Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue Then
MsgBox "lock"
Else
MsgBox "unlock"
End If
End If

Dim oRibbon As IRibbonUI
Set oRibbon = MainModule.gb_oMyRibbon1

oRibbon.InvalidateControl "MyToggleButton1"
End Sub
```

XML code (from comments)

```xml
<customUI onLoad="RibbonUI_onLoad1" xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="customTab" label="WIP">
                <group id="customGroup3" label="Organize">
                    <toggleButton id="MyToggleButton1" label="Lock" size="normal" imageMso="LockCell"
                                  onAction="Lock_and_Unlock"/>
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `getPressed` callback which enables you to specify whether the toggle button control is pressed. So, when you call the `InvalidateControl` method you ribbon callbacks are invalidated/invoked.

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#togglebutton)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Sub GetPressed(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
  'toggleState (i.e., true or false) determines how the 'toggle appears _
   on the ribbon (i.e., flusn or sunken).
  Select Case control.Id
    Case Is = "MyToggleButton1"
      If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse Then
        returnedVal = True
      Else
        returnedVal = False
      End If
  End Select
End Sub

Comment: Sub Lock_and_Unlock(control As IRibbonControl, pressed As Boolean)
  Select Case control.Id
    Case Is = "MyToggleButton1"
        If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse Then
            ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        Else
            ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        End If
    End Select
  'Force the ribbon to redefine the control wiht correct image and label
  myRibbon.InvalidateControl control.Id
  
  
End Sub

Comment: Sub RibbonUI_onLoad1(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
  'Creates a ribbon instance for use in this project
  Set myRibbon = ribbon
End Sub